# I get a syntax error after JQuery upgrade from 1.51 to 2

Tags: jquery, syntax-error

The code hasn't changed only the JQuery version. A simplified version of the ajax call is:

```
   $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'GET',
        url: MapPath($(this).attr('path')),
        cache: false,
        data: '{}',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            if ($(result).filter('#feedback').length > 0) {
                $('#center').children(':first').before($(result).filter('#feedback').outerHTML());
            }
            else {
                $('#feedback').remove();
                $('#dialog').html(result);
                $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'title', 'Edit Mailbox');
                $('#dialog').dialog('open');
            }
        }
    });
```

Just before the if statement I log the result. It shows as expected which is a properly formatted HTML snippet. Snippet meaning it contains a DIV with child elements. When I use the selector in the if statement I get the error:

```
throw Error("Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
```

I can use the console to view the contents of result and if I try any selector I get the error. I even get the error if I just use:

```
$(result)
```

However if I modify the result and prepend `<html><body>` and append `</body></html>` then it works with no error. What changed JQuery to break this and how do I work around it? The result needs to be an HTML snippet as I am setting a container on my page to the value.

Comment: [This blog post](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/) and [this one](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/01/jquery-migrate-1-2-0-released/) might be helpful. You probably don't want to upgrade all the way to jQuery 2.0 yet.

Comment: Most likely the html snippet starts with a string rather than HTML, which isn't allowed. This also doesn't look quite right: `$(result).filter('#feedback').outerHTML()` jQuery objects don't have an `outerHTML()` method.

Comment: Jquery 2.0 is meant for modern browsers only as mentioned in the articles that @Blazemonger linked, i would recommend using 1.9.1

Comment: @Blazemonger: After reading that I will stick with 1.9.1.

Comment: @Kevin B: outerHTML isn't the issue as it's another plugin I use. the error for sure happens with the filter statement. I don't know what you mean by string rather than HTML. It is a string but it starts with <div>. Are you suggesting white space is an issue?

Comment: For example, if anything comes before `<` in your html string, jQuery won't accept it unless you use `$.parseHTML` on the string first.

Comment: @Patsy Issa: I get the same issue with 1.9.1.

Comment: @ShawnDoe Is this wrong then? *"I even get the error if I just use: `$(result)`"*?

Comment: @Kevin B: When I log result the < in <div> seems to be the first character in the string.

Comment: @ShawnDoe Try using `$.parseHTML` anyway. `$( $.parseHTML(result) )`

Comment: @Kevin B: I get the error in the console if I try to use result with find, filter, a selector including result or just $(result) unless I make it a valid HTML document.

Comment: @ShawnDoe try using the error handler of ajax to log what's going wrong
 error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      //called when there is an error
    }

Comment: @Kevin B: Adding `result = $( $.parseHTML(result) )` as the first line in the success event resolves the issue.

Comment: @Patsy Issa: Apaprently I never make it to the error event of the ajax call. This error happens prior to that so I can't log those ajax error parameters.

Comment: @ShawnDoe Bear with me but can you double check the syntax of all your script tags that include jquery and other js files ?

Comment: @Patsy Issa: The snippet does include a script. The script syntax is: `<script src="/Areas/Webmail/Scripts/MailboxEdit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` which seems correct. Remember this all works with my older JQuery. I can't show you the syntax of the other scripts because I use combres to combine and minify them. But again it works the old way.

Comment: @PatsyIssa He is getting to the success callback, therefore the scripts are included properly and the ajax call is successful. The error is occurring *inside* the success callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I can't see your html string, I can't point out exactly what is causing it to not work with `$()`, however fixing it should be as easy as using `$.parseHTML()` on `result` first. If that doesn't parse it properly, the html is invalid.

```
result = $.parseHTML(result);
console.log(result);
if ($(result).filter('#feedback').length > 0) {
    $('#center').children(':first').before($(result).filter('#feedback').outerHTML());
}
else {
    $('#feedback').remove();
    $('#dialog').html(result);
    $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'title', 'Edit Mailbox');
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
}
```

Comment: I'll plan on that. The JQuery's rules for HTML must have gotten stricter. I don't have enough reputation to vote. I hope some nice person will. If I use an HTML validator I get: `This document was successfully checked as HTML 4.01 Strict!`.

Comment: @Shawn Doe: You should mark the answer as valid, if this was what you are looking for.

Comment: I cannot without a higher reputation. Will someone on this thread please mark this answer as valid?

Comment: @ShawnDoe It's the checkmark looking thing below the up and down vote buttons.

Comment: @Kevin B: I know but when I clicked it the other day it said I need a higher reputation to vote. Today it let me. It still won't let me vote on my other questions.

Comment: When you're at lower rep levels, you have to wait an amount of time before you can click it.