# Ajax request to get HTML doesn't execute scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen this question many times here with many different answers. This code stopped working when I moved from JQuery 1.5.1 to 1.9.1.

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: 'GET',
        url: MapPath($(this).attr('path')),
        cache: false,
        data: '{}',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (result) {
            result = $.parseHTML(result);

            $('#dialog').html(result);
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
            }
        }
    });
```

The result contains a link to a javascript file with a src attribute. Before I upgraded the script loaded and executed after being added to the #dialog container. Now it does not. From one suggestion I tried this after the parseHTML() method:

```
$.getScript("/myscript.js");
```

That works perfectly but that's not what I want. The loading container shouldn't have to know anything about the loaded container. If the loaded container needs a script include then that script needs to run when the container is loaded.

I've tried the suggestions of finding the script elements then eval() them. But once I parseHTML() the scripts simply aren't there anymore.  For why I have to use parseHTML() see my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442763/i-get-a-syntax-error-after-jquery-upgrade-from-1-51-to-2).

Maybe these things are related.

Comment: AJAX requests just grab a bunch of text data and store it somewhere. They will not automatically execute code unless specifically told to do so, and this is a Good Thing. You should do what you already have been advised to do: locate the link to the external JavaScript file and run it explicitly.

Comment: parseHTML has an optional parameter to include scripts (see the api), however i don't know whether or not it will first execute them.

Comment: If I change `result = $.parseHTML(result);` to `result = $.parseHTML(result, document, true);` it executes the script with no other changes. But is this safe?

Comment: Can someone with a higher reputation please mark this answer as valid. It does what I needed now.

Comment: I would have to do my own testing to consider it safe for my own work, but according to the documentation it looks safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unsafe to begin with loading scripts with html due to the way the browser will handle it (it may inconsistently execute before or after the html is ready to be manipulated). Instead, parse the string so that you can load the scripts later.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: MapPath($(this).attr('path')),
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {
        result = result.replace(/<script/ig, '<div class="i-script"')
                       .replace(/<\/script/ig, '</div');
        result = $.parseHTML(result);
        var scripts = $(result).find('.i-script').addBack().filter('.i-script').detach();
        $('#dialog').html(result);
        scripts.each(function(i,script){
            $.getScript($(script).attr('src'));
        });
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    }
});
```

Obviously, the code above will only work with external scripts, you could easily modify it to also work with inline.

Comment: I had to edit the code slightly: `result = result.replace(/<script/ig, '<div class="i-script"').replace(/<\/script/ig, '</div');` but once I did that seemed to work. I see the danger of having the scripts auto-run but I am looking for the most elegant way of making them run on demand.

Comment: Just a note, I have used this in the past, and it used to be the suggested way of handling page loading in history.js (it may still be). It should work pretty consistently.

Comment: This worked as well if someone would please mark this as valid. But I prefer the cleaner parseHTML method listed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) jQuery functionality. This method also executes any Javascript that is in the content that is being loaded.

```
$(container).load(src, function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
    alert(xhr.status + " | " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
```

Comment: If I change the line `$('#dialog').html(result);` to `$('#dialog').load(result);` and change nothing else the script does not get loaded. I saw this suggestion in other questions but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: What I am proposing would replace your entire $.ajax..... code. So yours should look like:  $('#dialog').load(MapPath($(this).attr('path')), function(response, status, xhr){ $('#dialog').dialog('open'); });

Comment: I'm not sure that could fit my model. In everyone of these cases I am using an ajax call to an MVC controller/action to return an HTML snippet that I add to container. Each snippet comes with its relevant script include.